# Uploading screen shots into stack exchange questions/answers

Tags: support

How can I upload screen shots into the a question to help someone answer a question for me?  I can't find any instructions on how to do it. I have tried pasting and dragging a jpeg into the question box but have had no joy. Could somebody please either tell me or direct me to the relevant page?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the meta site. You asked this on the right place. [Here's an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Also, for anyone coming to ask this again.. you need [at least **10rep** to do so](http://blender.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user).

Comment: @DantheMan Questions can't be dupes of questions on other sites. You can link to the MSO question, but people shouldn't have to check MSO before posting at Blender's meta.

Answer (score 4):

As a preventive measure against spam, users with less than 10 reputation have [some restrictions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user). Namely, new users cannot:

- **post images**
- post more than two hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their user profile
- contribute answers to protected questions
- ask or answer questions too rapidly

Once you've achieved ten reputation (as I see you now have), these restrictions are removed. Additionally, You can gain more privileges as you gain rep. For example, at 15 rep, you can vote up. At 50 rep, you can comment everywhere.

---

Once you have the ten reputation, you can insert an image by clicking the Image button (Ctrl + G).

[image]

From there, it's pretty straight-forward. Choose "From my computer" and select the image or choose "From the web" and insert a link.

The full page on markdown is [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You can find it by clicking the question mark in yellow and clicking "advanced help" (which Windows users never do).